# DocuSign API - Difference Between the formData array and the recipientFormData array

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the [EnvelopeFormData](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeFormData/get) to GET the form data for a specified envelope. I've noticed there are 2 arrays that are returned: `formData` and `recipientFormData`. They are both very similar and the name/value pairs from the `recipientFormData` array also appears in the `formData` array.

I haven't been able to find out what the difference between these is and whether I should be retrieving data from the `formData` or the `recipientFormData` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `recipientFormData` are the tabs (fields) organized per recipient (note the array).

Vs `formData` is the aggregate tab data for the envelope as a whole.

To test, use the method call with an envelope with multiple signing recipients, each with their own set of tabs.